# How to extract data from dynamic website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the restaurant name and address of each restaurant from this platform:

```
https://customers.dlivery.live/en/list
```

So far I tried with BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = 'https://customers.dlivery.live/en/list'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup
```

I noticed that within soup there is not the data about the restaurants.
How can I do this?

Comment: `https://api.yelo.red/` - within network tab

Answer (score 0):

if you `inspect element` the page, you will notice that the names are wrapped in the `card_heading` class, and the addresses are wrapped in `card_distance` class.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
restaurantAddress = soup.find_all(class_='card_distance')

for address in restaurantAddress:
   print(address.text)
```

and

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
restaurantNames = soup.find_all(class_='card_heading')

for name in restaurantNames:
   print(name.text)
```

Not sure if this exact code will work, but this is pretty close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the output of this ''soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')''  is not the HTML with the tags and class names that's what I was trying to said